# Import issues updating to exoplayer 2.18.2

Tags: android, gradle, exoplayer

I have updated `exoplayer` and the `exoplayer-extension-ima` version from `2.11.1` to the latest one (`2.18.2`).

Checking the [release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases) I just saw this on the version `2.18.1` section:
`This release corresponds to the AndroidX media3 1.0.0-beta02 release.`

So I thought I had to upgrade my exoplayer imports from `com.google.android.exoplayer2` to `androidx.media3` and I followed this [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/migration-guide) downloading the [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/ExoPlayer/r2.18.2/media3-migration.sh) for the `2.18.2` version and changing the `LEGACY_PEER_VERSION` variable from `2.18.1` to `2.18.2` and executing it withot getting any relevant error.

However after running the `assembleRelease` gradle script I'm facing the next errors:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension-level'. One of '{layoutlib}' is expected.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'extension-level'. No child element is expected at this point.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.

:myproject.exoplayer:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
ExoPlayerListener.java
package com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.ima does not exist
cannot find symbol class TrackGroupArray
package com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection does not exist
cannot find symbol class DefaultEventListener
cannot find symbol class ImaAdsLoader
cannot find symbol class ImaAdsLoader
cannot find symbol class TrackGroupArray
cannot find symbol class TrackSelectionArray
cannot find symbol class ImaAdsLoader
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
cannot find symbol variable super
```

On my ExoplayerListener.java some exoplayer imports changed (placing the mouse over them displays a `Cannot resolve symbol 'media3'` error)

```
import androidx.media3.common.Player;
import androidx.media3.common.TrackGroupArray;
```

And some don't (placing the mouse over them displays a `Cannot resolve symbol 'android'` error)

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.ima.ImaAdsLoader;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it perhaps that my steps towards the migration aren't correct?

Mention that I haven't changed anything on the code, just changing the below imports on the `build.gradle` file from:

```
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.11.1'
```

to:

```
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'
api 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.18.2'
```

And after the migration script changed to:

```
api 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.0-beta03'
api 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-ima:1.0.0-beta03'
```